# Limits: "does not exist" vs "cannot be evaluated"

Tags: limits, notation

Assuming we have a limit which doesn't exist, i.e.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}{f(x)} \not{\exists}$$

Is the above wording and notation mathematically equivalent to saying "The limit cannot be evaluated"? Of course, a limit that doesn't exist can't be evaluated. But can there be a limit that exists and yet cannot be evaluated?

Comment: At any rate "foo $\not\exists$" is not a good notation to say that the object foo does not exist

Comment: Depends on your definition of "evaluated". There are limits that exist but which we don't have nice, closed-form ways of writing. (Most convergent infinite series are examples of these.)

Comment: I would probably never say "the limit cannot be evaluated", unless I meant that it was too complicated to figure out analytically. If the limit does not exist, then it has indeed been evaluated (that doesn't mean that it has been assigned a definite numeric value -- the evaluation lead to the conclusion that the limit does not exist in such cases). Here, I  take "evaluate" to be synonymous with "analyze".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you're right; I have been using this notation for a long time and I should put more care into removing it from my writing.

Comment: @Dan I love your example with series very much. Thank you!

Comment: @MPW Most people I've spoken with seem to agree with you. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @juef: Happy to have helped! Regarding your notation, I agree with @Hagen von Eitzen, but wanted to add that it's more the order in which you've written things than using the symbol itself. Most people will understand what the shorthand "$\not\exists$ foo" means, so you don't have to completely change your habit. `:)`